# How to make navigation top bar style to same like "Black Navigation Bar" programmatically?

Tags: iphone

I have a Navigation project which has only a TableView. By default, I could see the navigation bar there when running the application. I want to change the navigation bar style to same like if we see in I.B there is one called "Top Bar" which has "Black Navigation Bar" style (Which shows Black navigation top bar but some kind of Gray shade will be there). I want the same in my navigation bar now, not any other color or style.
How do I fix it?

Note:

1. I used "self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;", but it shows the navigation bar in utter black color. I don't want that, I want some kind of Gray shade in black, similar to "Top Bar" which has "Black Navigation Bar".
2. I tried some tint color addition to the above, like "self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];" but I observe the same utter black shows in navigation bar.
3. I tried "navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;" but it doesn't fit and show with status bar properly. Instead it overlaps (hidden) half black with status bar and half black shows outside.

Could someone teach me?

Comment: Sorry "UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;" doesn't the one what i was expected. I want the color style same like, Open I.B, and check "Top Bar" which has "Black Navigation Bar". (or) Run your application which has set up "Top Bar" with "Black Navigation Bar", it will show black color with some shade of gray color.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean, but this could be because opaque and transparent lay out the internal view controller differently (view controller is visible through transparent one)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I tried "navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;" but it doesn't fit the navigation bar properly and show with the status bar there. Instead it overlaps(hiding) half part black navigation bar with status bar and other half shows outside on the top.

Comment: I got that i was hiding the status bar initially and then showing again when my TableView controller is launched where i have navigation bar also. Due to this, i observed the above comment issue of half-in half-out. Now, i just kept the status bar ON always, doesn't observer overlapping of navigation bar and status bar, BUT it has set "UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent", but output is still utter black color style only.

Comment: Sounds weird. any chance you could put up a screenshot?

Answer (score 10):

As `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent` is deprecated in iOS 3.0,
it is better to use those two lines:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;  // optional
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

This also allows you to use a different color than black.

Answer (score 7):

```
navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

([docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarStyle))

Answer (score 6):

Full answer...

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MyView *myView=[[MyView alloc]initWithNibName:@"myView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView];
[nav.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.blackTranslucent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard choose `Translucent Black Navigation Bar` for Top Bar
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change the bar style to **black-translucent** ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar))

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.99997437, blue: 0.9999912977, alpha: 1)
```